# IOS Printing PDF from WebView and Page is slightly offset

Tags: objective-c, ios, webview

I am using the code below to print a PDF from a Webview called "webby". When I print the PDF, the page output shows the previous page on top.  In other words, if I print page 3, it shows the last line of page 2 on page 3, and the bottom of page 3 does not print.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or should change?

```
UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];


UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;

printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
print.printInfo = printInfo;
print.showsPageRange = YES;

UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [self.webby viewPrintFormatter];
viewFormatter.startPage = 0;
print.printFormatter = viewFormatter;


UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {};

[print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used the near about same code just little bit changes

can you please try below code

```
- (IBAction)printWebPage:(id)sender
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if(!controller){

        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = 
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if(!completed && error){

        }
    };


    // Obtain a printInfo so that we can set our printing defaults.
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    // This application produces General content that contains color.
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    // We'll use the URL as the job name
    printInfo.jobName = @"";
    // Set duplex so that it is available if the printer supports it. We
    // are performing portrait printing so we want to duplex along the long edge.
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    // Use this printInfo for this print job.
    controller.printInfo = printInfo;

    // Be sure the page range controls are present for documents of > 1 page.
    controller.showsPageRange = YES;

    // This code uses a custom UIPrintPageRenderer so that it can draw a header and footer.
    MyPrintPageRenderer *myRenderer = [[MyPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
    // The MyPrintPageRenderer class provides a jobtitle that it will label each page with.
    myRenderer.jobTitle = printInfo.jobName;
    // To draw the content of each page, a UIViewPrintFormatter is used.
    UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [webviwReport viewPrintFormatter];

#if SIMPLE_LAYOUT
    /*
     For the simple layout we simply set the header and footer height to the height of the
     text box containing the text content, plus some padding.

     To do a layout that takes into account the paper size, we need to do that 
     at a point where we know that size. The numberOfPages method of the UIPrintPageRenderer 
     gets the paper size and can perform any calculations related to deciding header and
     footer size based on the paper size. We'll do that when we aren't doing the simple 
     layout.
     */
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10]; 
    CGSize titleSize = [myRenderer.jobTitle sizeWithFont:font];
    myRenderer.headerHeight = myRenderer.footerHeight = titleSize.height + 5;
#endif
    [myRenderer addPrintFormatter:viewFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
    // Set our custom renderer as the printPageRenderer for the print job.
    controller.printPageRenderer = myRenderer;
    [myRenderer release];

    // The method we use presenting the printing UI depends on the type of 
    // UI idiom that is currently executing. Once we invoke one of these methods
    // to present the printing UI, our application's direct involvement in printing
    // is complete. Our custom printPageRenderer will have its methods invoked at the
    // appropriate time by UIKit.

    //    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    //        [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:printButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPad
    //    else
    //        [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPhone
    [controller presentFromRect:CGRectMake(btnReportPrint.frame.origin.x, btnReportPrint.frame.origin.y+40, btnReportPrint.frame.size.width, btnReportPrint.frame.size.height) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Changing the titleSize.height + 5 added additional space to push the previous page down further, but I was unable to adjust it to remove it from the page.

Comment: thanks but how to change the backround colour in controller ..or set image any thing ??? thanks in advance :) @GeoffreyMoore

Comment: i know its too late but you might want to read the discussion from this link https://discussions.apple.com/message/13146925#13146925