# Print webview content in single page

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I’m trying to print the web view content from my device its working fine without  any problem but its coming in two pages i wanted with in one page. I have the changed the print setting before i give the print but its only coming half content in one page.

Printing code,

```
- (IBAction)print:(id)sender {

     UIPrintInfo *pi = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
     pi.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
     pi.jobName = webview.request.URL.absoluteString;
     pi.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
     pi.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

     UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
     pic.printInfo = pi;
     pic.showsPageRange = YES;
     pic.printFormatter = webview.viewPrintFormatter;
    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic2, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

    }]; 
  }
```

Am I missing anything in code? Do I have to change my printer settings? Kindly advice.

Thanks!

Comment: which printer you are using ?

Comment: @Rushabh   HP printer model number m1218

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356 check this link and check your printer supported by iOS.

Comment: @Rushabh i have checked but its printing the content the only thing its not coming in the single page thats the problem

Comment: @user3349668 : check mention link, may be it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597042/ios-printing-pdf-from-webview-and-page-is-slightly-offset